# Grid of fixed number of rows and columns - android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I want to create a grid or table of fixed number of rows and columns(Ex. 6x6 grid) in a layout of Android Studio. I tried using GridLayout and GridView but it requires you to put 36 EditText(Plain text) Views in it for creating a 6x6 grid. Same is the case with TableLayout where you can only insert TableRows but cannot fix the number of columns.

```
Bottom line is, I want a 6x6 grid which has only a 6-letter word(one character in each cell) in the beginning and one letter is typed in every turn to make a word with the existing letters.
```

For this, from any cell, I should be able to read the characters in the adjacent cells. I don't think creating a GridView or TableLayout and creating 36 objects of EditTextView will be the best idea. Is there a good and efficient way to do this?  I need the .xml file code and also its Java class file's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't think that creating a layout holding views in Android framework is good and efficient way for exposing some data in a graphical interface? This is the only reason for which View class even exists. It's a main building material of your application's GUI.

Also you don't need to create it by hand. You just need to be able to address your [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) (Layout) object from your Java code where you build your Activity instance. From there you have an `addView()` method and you can add views in a simple loop (notice that this way you can create grids of every size, not only 6x6).

Please familiarize yourself with official [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/index.html) site where you can read pretty much about anything relating Android Framework. For more info about layouts click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this library it might help you.
https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders